# Firebase Error : Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried to implement Firebase on my React.JS app for authentification. However, I keep getting this error

> ERROR in ./src/Pages/UserPage/contexts/AuthContext.js 8:0-32

> Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package /Users/Aarnav/Desktop/JavaScript/my-app copy 2/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /Users/Aarnav/Desktop/JavaScript/my-app copy 2/node_modules/firebase/package.json)

My firebase setup looks like this,

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCPSbjZ9F1TgI43T0SH68rUi9TMHBXRw - s",
  authDomain: "csia-41409.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://csia-41409-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "csia-41409",
  storageBucket: "csia-41409.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "714268776254",
  appId: "1:714268776254:web:93d9ef26a5d9c7d7f8be6f",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth();
```

and my authcontext looks

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { auth } from "firebase";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

   useEffect(() => {
     const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       setCurrentUser(user);
       setLoading(false);
     });

     return unsubscribe;
   }, []);

  auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    setCurrentUser(user);
  });

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    login,
    signup,
  };
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Also for some reason my entire website is a blank white screen no matter which router(page) I am on. I believe this is because of the error mentioned on top but I am not sure.

At first I thought it was because I was using firebase version 9.14 however, I updated my setup for firebase but it was to no avail and the error still presisted. I have no idea how to remove the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In firebase V9, you should do signup and login with email and password in this way:

```js
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
```

```js
const auth = getAuth();

function signup(email, password) {
  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}

function login(email, password) {
  return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
}
```